# Pausing & Resuming in Media Player

Tags: wpf, vb.net, media-player

Currently im building a media player in Wpf VB.net. Im Stuck at play and pause button. It can pause but once i click play, the song started from beginning.I want it to resume from where i pause. Need your help guys.Below is my code

```
 Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click

        mplayer.Open(New Uri(ImagePath & iPodList.SelectedValue, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))


        If btnPlay.Content = "Play" Then
            mplayer.Play()
            btnPlay.Content = "Pause"

        ElseIf btnPlay.Content = "Pause" Then
            mplayer.Pause()
            btnPlay.Content = "Play"

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I've edited your title to something descriptive of the problem. Tags do not belong in titles.

Comment: what is `mplayer`? Is it a `MediaElement`? You need to provide ALL the relevant information and what type(s) you're using is ALWAYS relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `mplayer` is, I would assume that the fact that you call `Open` on it every time you click that `Button` would be the issue. If you want to pause and resume what is already playing then don't open something new.

Comment: Hi, If i remove the open then i cannot play songs as well. What i supposed to do/call if wan to resume the song

Comment: You are supposed to call `Open` when and ONLY when you want to start playing a song for the first time, not every time you pause and resume. You need to put some thought into what you want to do under what circumstances and the structure of the code to accomplish that.

Comment: Note that this question, and thus this answer, is about pausing and resuming. If you take the `Open` call out of that event handler and put it elsewhere, e.g. the `Click` of another `Button`, does the pause and resume code work? If so, this issue is resolved and the question answered. How to open the media properly is a different subject and so doesn't belong in this question. Give it some thought though. Presumably you only want to open new media when the user selects new media, not every time they pause and resume, so how do you detect that?